# How to fill addMultiOptions with data from database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, zend-framework

What I want to create is a form with an select field. The items in the select
field are categories, I want to put them from the database into the form addMultiOptions.

Hope some one can help me.

With kind regards,

Nicky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Zend_Db_Table_Abstract, and Zend Form, you could do this:

```
$result = $model->fetchAll()->toArray();
$options = array();

foreach ($result as $value) {
    $options[$value['id']] = $value['whatEver'];
}

$field = new Zend_Form_Element_Select();
$field->setMultiOptions($options);
```

Or from an Controller:

```
$model = new My_Model_WhatEver();
$result = $model->fetchAll()->toArray();
$options = array();

foreach ($result as $value) {
    $options[$value['id']] = $value['whatEver'];
}

$form = new My_Form_WhatEver();
$element = $form->getElement('whatEver');
$element->setMultiOptions($result);
```

Comment: That code could lead to strange result because in that way the id values of the select boxes will be the numeric indexes of the resultset and all the values will be the `Array` string. To use a query result directly in `setMultiOptions` you should use the [`fetchPairs` method](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/_Db_Adapter_Abstract.html#%5CZend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::fetchPairs())

Comment: you are right, but i have "fixed" the example.  fetchPairs is more sexy ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use one or more of the [Zend_Form_Element_Multi](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/_Form_Element_Multi.html#%5CZend_Form_Element_Multi) methods. If you have an array in the form

```
array(
  'id1' => 'value 1',
  'id2' => 'value 2',
);
```

You can add all of them by using `setMultiOptions` method. If you instead need to add options inside a `foreach` loop, you have to use `addMultiOption` method which add an option at time with

```
foreach ($array as $id => $value) {
  $element->addMultiOption($id, $value);
}
```